# Jenkins 2.0, failure to execute goals- maven is unable to pickup ojdbc dependency

Tags: maven, jenkins, ojdbc

My Jenkins build is failing with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oneone: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.nike:oneone:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure
>   to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4.0-atlassian-hosted in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.4.0-atlassian-hosted</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone know if there is there a way around it?

Comment: This part will not be in maven central and that's simply the problem..you need to download an ojdbc driver manually from oracle sites and install it into your local repository manager....

Comment: The thing that puzzles me the most is that it works perfectly fine on my local box, but fails in Jenkins.

Comment: On your local box might a version installed sometime ago manually but not on Jenkins I suppose..

Comment: I'm using maven in both cases. On my local box it is able to acquire all the dependencies, but not on the Jenkins.

Comment: Just try to delete the local cache on your local box `$HOME/.m2/repository`  and see if it works...if yes than the configuration on your CI system is wrong...

Comment: I was able to find the necessary dependency by utilizing commercial version. That solved the issue.